# Let's get critical: Mar 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Linguistics Stack Exchange](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is word order a method of implementing case in English language](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11357/is-word-order-a-method-of-implementing-case-in-english-language)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the root of an utterance without a verb?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11144/what-is-the-root-of-an-utterance-without-a-verb)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can present tense be more marked?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11355/can-present-tense-be-more-marked)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Glottal stops that aren't tenuis](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11191/glottal-stops-that-arent-tenuis)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Diphthongs ending in unusual vowels?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/diphthongs-ending-in-unusual-vowels)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Semitic: *w > y](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11146/semitic-w-y)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What kind of wordplay is this?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11369/what-kind-of-wordplay-is-this)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Evaluate idea to autobuild russian-english parallel corpus](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11195/evaluate-idea-to-autobuild-russian-english-parallel-corpus)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Origin of Language as Commands?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/origin-of-language-as-commands)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How do we get "four" when it doesn't follow Grimm's law?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/11334/how-do-we-get-four-when-it-doesnt-follow-grimms-law)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

Answer (score -2):

By far it's the best Linguistics Community on the net. Like everything else SE does. Thanks you guys for just being there.